# How to configure GeoPoint in a Flutter class?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

Somehow, I can't get this code to work:

My model is this:

```
class Location {
  final String name;
  final String route;
  final String id;
  final GeoPoint location;
  final List images;
  final String address;

  Location(
      {this.name,
      this.route,
      this.id,
      this.location,
      this.images,
      this.address});
}
```

Here's the Firebase snapshot that works just fine without the `location` field.

```
List<Location> _locationListFromSnapshot(QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
    return snapshot.docs.map((doc) {
      return Location(
          name: doc["name"]["ru"] ?? '',
          route: doc["route"] ?? '',
          address: doc["address"]["ru"] ?? '',
          images: doc["images"],
          id: doc['id'] ?? '',
          location: doc["location"]);
    }).toList();
  }
```

Here's the error thrown:

```
Unhandled Exception: Bad state: field does not exist within the DocumentSnapshotPlatform
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the code works fine without the `location` field, then it means that the `location` field does not exist in the document.

Comment: You were right. Just to clarify. It was a mistake in the database. One of the documents lacked the field. Thanks